# Can't read a csv file using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, ibm-watson

I am trying to use the IBM Watson Studio Jupyter Notebook to open a csv file but I just can't do it

So typing the normal pandas command will give me the FileNotFoundError

This command

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Gaming\Downloads\clean_gdp.csv')
```

When I ask for to currently working directory with `os.getcwd()` it returns this

```
/home/dsxuser/work
```

But when I ask to change the currently working directory using `os.chdir()` it just gives me the `FileNotFoundError` using this:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\\Users\\Gaming\\Downloads')
```

Comment: Also I did not forget to import pandas as pd first

Comment: Since you are using absolute path, there is no need to check current working directory. Can you please verify if clean_gdp.csv is really existed by opening "C:\Users\Gaming\Downloads" and check if you can see the file there?

Comment: Is your notebook on the cloud or local?

Comment: why is your os.chdir having raw string r as well as double slashes ?